# Solving this recurrence without the master theorem. Backtracking Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity, notation

I've made a backtracking algorithm. 
I've been asked to say what is the complexity of this Algo. 
I know that the equation is T(n) = 2T(n-1) + 3(n_hat), where n_hat is the initial n. Meaning it doesn't decrease in each step.

The thing is that I'm getting quite lost on calculating this thing. I believe it's around 2**n * something. But my calculations are a bit confusing. Can you help me please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's expand this formula repeatedly by substituting into itself:

[image]